# How to highlight questions with watched tags on the Home page?

Tags: support, tag-watching

The [Home](https://stackoverflow.com/) page of Stack Overflow used to highlight questions with my watched tags but does not do that anymore since a few days ago. What's the deal?

I am a casual Stack Overflow contributor. I do not want to search for my favorite questions actively by clicking the tag in the *Watched Tags* section. I want to be presented with the newest questions, some of which are highlighted. As it used to be.

How can I resurrect the old behavior?

Comment: @Sabito錆兎 At this time, the linked questions does not have an answer or a comment that would suggest a solution. The cause may very well be the DOM change that broke jQuery selection as mentioned in [another answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/366345/23354).

Comment: Yeah. BTW shouldn't this be tagged [bug]?

Comment: @Sabito錆兎 I cannot tell whether this is a bug or an intended change.

Comment: It's a bug. The developers said they fixed it, but it doesn't seem like the fix is working for everyone.

Comment: Still not highlighting for me in in desktop Chrome 91.0.4472.101.

Comment: Seems to be fixed, now.